# Polymer handler not working in my application

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have created custom polymer component named Test_custom.html and I Included that created polymer component in index.html file. Then added tag inside the body and created polymer component functionality working fine without any issue.

Sample index.html

```
<html>
    <head>        
         <script src="assets/polymer/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>  

         <link rel="import" href="assets/app/polymerComponents/Tester/Test_custom.html" />        
    </head>
    <body>
         <test-comp></test-comp> <!-- working fine it has some button on click display message-->
    </body>
</html>
```

In case if I want to use that component inside my application then it is not invoking the polymer handler

My project structure as follow

```
app

   pages

        component

               component.html

               component .ts
```

sample code for

```
 Test_custom.html

    <dom-module id="test-comp">
      <template>  <!-- this part is working without any issue-->
      </template>

        <script>
               var MtCompare = Polymer({
                is: "test-comp",
                properties: {
                         }


                ready: function () {
                    var self = this;
                    this.initHandlers();
                    }


      initHandlers: function () {

                    $('.button_test').on('click', function () {
                        //doing operation
                    });
                    }

                  });
        </script>

    </dom-module>
```

Comment: Did you bower install and import Polymer? It looks like you've set your bower_components folder to `assets/polymer/` according to your webcomponentsjs import. (That's a bit misleading with the name there, I would just use `assets/bower_components`). You should have a `<link rel="import" href="../../../../polymer/polymer/polymer.html">` at the top of `Test_custom.html`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand that question but shouldn't be the file name the same is your dom-module id!?
In addition to that, you are missing the comma, although I believe this is not needed in polymer 2 anymore. 
I am also not sure about your class selector this might be also a Polymer two thing I do't know about but I would have used a querySelector() or an ID (this.$.buttonID
Even easier would be to at a on-tap function to the button?!
So for a file named "test-custom.html" the Polymer Element should look like this:

```
<dom-module id="test-custom">

  <template>
  </template>

  <script>
    var MtCompare = Polymer({
      is: "test-comp",
      properties: {
      },

      ready: function () {
        this.initHandlers();
      },

      initHandlers: function () {
      var button = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('.button_test');
        button.on('click', function () {
          //doing operation
        });
      }

    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```